# Too many image textures causing pink shading?

Tags: texturing, shaders, texture-painting

I am testing the use of a mask to create a paint with shaders texture but while creating the materials with the textures I am using it seems that after adding 9 seperate image textures it all turns pink. Is there a max amount of image textures you can use in the shader editor? Or is something else happening.

Comment: Can you elaborate on using 9 images, are you talking about full float images or just small generated 2k images, what memory size are we talking here? Did you possibly hit a memory limit with your GPU?

Comment: Its possible I did, 9 seperate 4K images definitely overloaded it. How could I get around this limit? Would baking it help?

Comment: Not sure of what you are trying to achieve here, but yes consider baking down some of the images to what you need to be showing, since if you are combining them partially or using each to affect each other the end result doesn't require processing 9 4k images, you  are only seeing a single image result. Side question - do you get the same limit with CPU display?